# DLOOKUP vs Multiple SELECT queries

Tags: mysql

I need help writing a query that will look up contact names multiple times.

I have two database tables...tblCONTACTS and tblPOLICIES.

tblCONTACTS has two fields, ID and CONTACTNAME.  tblPOLICIES has 4 fields POL_ID, OWNER, ASSIGNEE, BENEFICIARY.  Other than POL_ID, the other 3 fields are references to ID in the table tblCONTACTS.

How do I write a query to select all of the records in tblPOLICIES, but return the names from tblCONTACTS (instead of the ID that is contained in that field)?

Sorry if this is too amateur for this forum?  I think I can do this with a Dlookup function in MS Access but am worried about performance.  My other solution was to write multiple queries and the string the multiple queries together.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you have a good idea about how to fix this problem. We're much more helpful if you have a specific question regarding code you've written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    a.POL_ID,
    b.CONTACTNAME as OWNER,
    c.CONTACTNAME as ASSIGNEE,
    d.CONTACTNAME as BENEFICIARY
FROM Test.tblPOLICIES as a 
LEFT JOIN Test.tblCONTACTS as b ON a.OWNER = b.ID
LEFT JOIN Test.tblCONTACTS as c ON a.ASSIGNEE = c.ID
LEFT JOIN Test.tblCONTACTS as d ON a.BENEFICIARY = d.ID;
```

Will give you this result:

[image]

Regards

Comment: Thanks!  This was perfect.  I guess I needed a primer on LEFT JOINS.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: You welcome, I would appreciate a vote or accepting the answer. Regards